# How do I apply text translation to map elements?

Tags: reactjs, localization, internationalization

Added part of the code. The values of this object must be translated, everything should be dynamic

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
...
  const { t } = useTranslation()
....
        const overlayMaps = {
            "Clouds": clouds, 
            "Cloudscls": cloudscls,
            "Precipitation": precipitation,
            "Precipitationcls": precipitationcls,
            "Rain": rain,
            "Raincls": raincls,
            "snow": snow,
            "Pressure": pressure,
            "Pressurecntr": pressurecntr,
            "Temp": temp,
            "Wind": wind
        };
...
```

It doesn't work that way:

```
        const overlayMaps = {
            {t("clouds")}: clouds, 
            "Cloudscls": cloudscls,
            "Precipitation": precipitation,
            "Precipitationcls": precipitationcls,
            "Rain": rain,
            "Raincls": raincls,
            "snow": snow,
            "Pressure": pressure,
            "Pressurecntr": pressurecntr,
            "Temp": temp,
            "Wind": wind
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for computed prop object you can use this way:

```js
const overlayMaps = {
  [t('clouds')]: clouds,
  [t('Cloudscls')]: cloudscls,
  [t('Precipitation')]: precipitation,
  [t('Precipitationcls')]: precipitationcls,
  [t('Rain')]: rain,
  [t('Raincls')]: raincls,
  [t('snow')]: snow,
  [t('Pressure')]: pressure,
  [t('Pressurecntr')]: pressurecntr,
  [t('Temp')]: temp,
  [t('Wind')]: wind,
};
```